# include (upper left) part of pdf as graphic

Tags: graphics, miktex

I have a pdf containing a plot (testpdf.pdf, for testing purposes I took this [sample][1] one). I would like to include this plot within another document. Unfortunately plot.pdf has a margin at the bottom and right. I would like to include the upper left part say (3in x 5in) of the image and resize this part to a width of 19cm.

In "bigpoints" this translates to the upper left part 216bp x 300bp.

And then tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left = 0mm, right = 0mm, bottom = 0mm, top = 13mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
\includegraphics[bb = 0 300 216 0, clip, width = 19cm]{testpdf}
\end{document}
```

I used the xelatex compiler. Unfortunately this does not seem to work and the result is empty. Any help/ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to just crop out the bottom right cruft using `pdfcrop` or some graphics program.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to perl on this machine (an therefore no pdfcrop). Therefore looking for another solution. I also tried using [trim = ...]. But unfortuately I do not know the size of the pdf containing the plot beforehand (since they are generated automatically). It would help if I could find out the totalwidth / totalheight of the pdf to include programmatically (is this possible?) I could then calculate the width / height of the margin.

Comment: Which distribution do you have?

Comment: The distcibution I have is miktex 2.9 on win7

Comment: Your value is negative, try `bb= 0 0 216 300`.

Comment: Unfortunately latex measures from the bottom left. How do I get the 216bpx300bp rectangle at the top left? The pdf containing the graphic (uncropped) is larger than the target pdf.

Comment: I tried finding the pdfs dimensions with 
\settowidth{\imagewidth}{\includegraphics{plot}}
\settoheight{\imageheight}{\includegraphics{plot}}
but the returned height and width were smaller than expected and cropped the image even when using \includegraphics[viewport = 0 0 \imagewidth{} \imageheight{}, clip]{plot}

Comment: Is XeLaTeX required? With pdfTeX you can do this using `\pdfximage`.

Comment: Hmmm, yes. I'm using xelatex because of easy(ier) integration of fonts. A solution using xelatex therefore prefered